# How to create a simultaneously playing audio stack from different audio files in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-audio

I'm working on a Mac OS X application using Cocoa in Xcode. One feature involves a simultaneous audio playback:

I want to build some kind of audio stack: An audio file merged in runtime from a set of different source files. The set of source audio files differs each runtime. Each Audio file has the exact same length.

After creating the audio stack (or merged file) I want to play [and store] it.

I'm new to audio frameworks in Cocoa. Is there a high-level API that provides an appropriate functionality? Do I have to look inside the CoreAudio, Audio Unit or QTKit framework? Do you have an implementation idea (or sample implementation)?

Comment: Do you actually need to create a (virtual?) merged file, or would it be sufficient to just play them all at the same time (or starting within a few ms of each other)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to play a bunch of audio files simultaneously, this is easy; unlikes Windows, OS X acts as if it has an infinite-channel mixer built-in, and all the higher-level functions just grab a new channel if necessary for each sound. For example:

```
NSURL *u1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"1" withExtension:@"mp3"];  
NSURL *u2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"2" withExtension:@"mp3"];
NSSound *s1 = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u1 byReference:YES];
NSSound *s2 = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u2 byReference:YES];
[s1 play];
[s2 play];
```

This will start playing MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/1.mp3 and MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/2.mp3 at (very close to) the same time.

If you need a (real or virtual) file with a bunch of audio tracks in them, QTKit is probably the easiest way; create a movie, open all of your audio files, copy their tracks into the movie (with the same start date), and now you can play the movie (or do whatever else you want).

If you want to actually merge the audio into one stereo track (e.g., so you can save a normal audio file), instead of just playing the tracks together at runtime, you could use QTKit as above and create an export session (much like using the "Export…" feature in QuickTime Player), or use CoreAudio, or a variety of different cross-platform open source libraries.